# Disable Chrome smooth scrolling

Tags: google-chrome

I find smooth scrolling in Chrome really annoying.. it continues to scroll on even after I stop the mouse wheel. I tried disabling Smooth scrolling in `chrome://flags/` but it had no effect.

Comment: Did you restart Chrome after disabling the flag? If it's still not working try turning off hardware acceleration and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I did restart. Hardware acceleration was turned off from before.

Comment: Which operating system is this Chrome on?

Comment: it is on windows 10

Answer (score 2):

If you have smooth scrolling disabled in Chrome flags, but some site still does it, it can be:

1. Site uses CSS `scroll-behavior` property (which now affects even navigation to next/previous occurrences of text search). Example of site doing this: developer.mozilla.org

This is very easy to solve:

1) Install Stylebot extension

2) Go to its Options/styles/edit global stylesheet, and add this rule:

```
*
    {
        scroll-behavior: initial;
    }
```

It will solve the problem for this and all similar sites.

2. Site uses some javascript library that does non-native smooth scrolling

If you can afford to disable javascript for this site - this is easy to solve (click the secure/not secure label to the left of the address bar,  Site settings/Javascript/Block).

Otherwise it might be possible to solve on case-by-case basis. For example, if you usually scroll pages with arrow keys, and smooth-scrolling interferes with it - it has to catch keyboard events, so you can try to block all keydown events with this userscript (for Tampermonkey extension):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         disable smooth scroll on somesite.com
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @author       You
// @match        https://somesite.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }, true );
```

This works for me on one site, which otherwise adds an "ease" effect to the scrolling done by Up/Down keys.